# Why is sonarLint saying 'Close this "Stream"' on Stream.of() but not on .stream()

Tags: sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

I am using the sonarLint plugin in eclipse

On this line i get 'Close this "Stream"'

> Stream.concat(Stream.of("a"),
>   Stream.of("b")).collect(Collectors.toSet());

but not on

> Arrays.asList("a", "b").stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());

I don't understand why not its not the same message on both lines.
I am not sure if this is a java question or a sonarlint question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue already fixed in the upcoming version (3.14) of the java plugin : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1478

See this other question for more details : [When is an IntStream actually closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34768792/when-is-an-intstream-actually-closed)